# How to write multiple instruction in Objective-C macro?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros

I wonder how to write multiple instruction in Objective C macro.
For example, I want to create a macro which runs two instructions below,

```
NSLog(message);
DDLogDebug(message);
```

I tried,

```
#define LOGMESSAGE(message) (NSLog(message);DDLogDebug(message);)
```

But it gave me compiler errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write multiple line macro like this:

`#define LOGMESSAGE(message)    \
            NSLog(message);      \
            DDLogDebug(message); \`

Or use one line version (whithout parenthesis):

```
#define LOGMESSAGE(message) NSLog(message);DDLogDebug(message);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped!

Comment: One technique is to use a `do { ... } while (0)` wrapper as it removes the possibility of some tricky bugs. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/